# Best method to obtain a list of the most recent N photos across all interesting Facebook albums?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I've put together this code to fetch data for the last `MAX_PHOTOS` from a given Facebook account (fb_id), excluding those in `EXCLUDED_ALBUM_TYPES`. I think I'm done with this Graph API for now... Unless anyone can come up with a better way?

```
# itertools.chain, with parse_datetime from Django

def get_facebook_photos(self, fb_id):
    EXCLUDED_ALBUM_TYPES = ['profile', 'cover', 'wall', ]
    MAX_PHOTOS = 20
    albums = fb_client.get_object('{}/albums?fields=id,type'.format(fb_id)).get('data', [])
    photos = []
    album_ids = [a['id'] for a in albums if a['type'] not in EXCLUDED_ALBUM_TYPES]
    # No prefix for this path.
    photos_path = '/photos?ids={}&fields=source,link,created_time.order(reverse_chronological)'.format(
        ','.join(album_ids))
    photos_data = chain.from_iterable(photos['data'] for photos in fb_client.get_object(photos_path).values())
    for i, photo in enumerate(photos_data):
        if i == MAX_PHOTOS:
            break
        photos.append({
            'src': photo['source'],
            'link': photo['link'],
            'time': parse_datetime(photo['created_time'])
        })

    return photos
```

I suppose I could try limiting the number of albums retrieved. `limit` in the `photos_path` querystring sets a limit on the number of photo items per album, which isn't what I want. For now I'm relying on the default response pagination for performance, with a Django template fragment cache for the gathered images (they're displayed in a carousel). Admittedly, saying all that leads me to wonder why it hasn't simply been done on the frontend with JS...

Comment: _"why it hasn't simply been done on the frontend with JS..."_ - well you would have to make users login to your app first, so that you can use their access token. (App or page tokens, or tokens not belonging to the current user should of course not get exposed in client-side code.) Plus, making such requests on every page load would likely make your app run into the Rate Limits rather quickly; doing this server-side makes it easier to implement some form of caching to prevent that.

Comment: Good point, now I remember.